# How to get XHP working in hack/hhvm on Ubuntu

Tags: hacklang, xhp

I've installed hack-nightly and set up fastcgi using nginx by following the instructions on the website, however I'm getting an error when trying to create a simple file that uses xhp:

```
<?hh
$x = <html><body>hello</body></html>;
echo $x->toString();
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class undefined: xhp_html in /
```

Is there a step I need to take to enable this, or an additional import or package to install?

Comment: Good question! Simon's answer is right on, I created an issue for this if you want to follow along: https://github.com/hhvm/hack-hhvm-docs/issues/128

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the XHP library, which you can find [here](https://github.com/facebook/xhp/tree/master/php-lib). This defines the :xhp base class as well as all the HTML classes. Put all three files somewhere in your source tree then include init.php before doing anything with XHP.

There's currently a discussion going on in the HHVM.dev group on Facebook about if the library should be included by default or not, which you can view at https://www.facebook.com/groups/hhvm.dev/229787297210377/.

Comment: Thanks, I've added: "require "/vagrant/thing/xhp/php-lib/init.php";" to my file but now I'm getting the following error in the server output: Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /vagrant/thing/xhp/php-lib/core.php on line 18

Comment: @PaulJohnson You'll have to enable XHP syntax in your .hdf file, or change the core.php and lib.php files to have `<?hh //decl` as the opening tag since XHP class name syntax is supported out of the box in Hack. You can follow up at https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2278 for more details.